# Use multiple expressions in grep consumer

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have these bash functions

```
filter_history(){
  grep -v '^cd[^ ]|^ls[^ ]'
}

get_clean_bash_history(){
  cat "$HOME/.bash_history" | filter_history
}
```

I am trying to get the bash history but filter out boring commands like `cd` and `ls`...but my grep expression doesn't work, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the -E flag was necessary to use with grep, this appears to work:

```
grep -v -E '^cd +|^ls +'
```

but please correct me if this is not sufficient or fails in edge cases

Comment: Alternative without `-E` and a lot of escaping:  `grep -v '^\(cd\|ls\) \+'`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to escape the `or`:

```
function get_clean_bash_history(){
    grep -v '^cd \|^ls ' "$HOME/.bash_history"
}
```